# Page constantly refreshing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have a Dynamics CRM page which is using Javascript.
When the page loads, the `Deposit_OnLoad()` is called, and when the `wa_clientaccountid` field changes, the `OnClientAccountChanged()` function is called.
However, when this page is loaded in Google Chrome, the page is constantly refreshing, about once every second. But when the page is loaded in IE, it does not constantly refresh.
Why is this?

```js
function Deposit_OnLoad() {
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("wa_clientaccountid").fireOnChange();

    //Make the form controls readonly. 
    if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 2) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get().forEach(function (control, index) {
            if (control.getControlType() != "iframe") {
                control.setDisabled(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

function OnClientAccountChanged() {
    var clientAccountValueArray = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("wa_clientaccountid").getValue();
    if (clientAccountValueArray == null) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("transactionsummarytab").setVisible(false);
        return;
    }
    var clientAccountGuid = clientAccountValueArray[0].id;
    var clientId = GetClientIdFromClientAccountGuid(clientAccountGuid);
    if (clientId != null) {
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("transactionsummarytab").setVisible(true);
    }
    var url = BuildReportIFrameNewUrl(clientId);
    SetReportIFrameUrl(url);
}

function SetReportIFrameUrl(url) {
    Xrm.Page.getControl(transactionSummaryName).setSrc(url);
}
```

Comment: Function `Deposit_OnLoad` executes `OnClientAccountChange` which sets an URL using function `SetReportIFrameUrl`. Does the last function behave as expected?

Comment: I just edited my post with that function.

Comment: Do you have any logic which might be firing something like an onchange event which might save the form, maybe?